# How to stop page from reloding each time a dropdown menu is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website and I have a design issue coming up. I have a navigation bar where 3 dropdowns are present. Whenever I click on the dropdown and select an item, the page completely reloads and the whole structure of webpage fully refreshes and need to scroll down again and again for checking that clicked option. Is there something that can stop it from reloading each time and when a menu item is clicked the page stays right at there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `<a href="about.html">About</a>`
Use `<a href="#about">About</a>`

If you point the href to an html file then it will reload the page but if you use a section's id then it will go to that section of the page without reloading.

Comment: Thanks for the time . But I would like to point out that the href part has php files as .php extensions. Will it be okay if I go as you are saying @AhmetOmer